# Dual of topological vector space

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Assume $E$ is an infinite dimensional vector space. Assume $\tau_1, \tau_2$ are two topologies that make $E$ into topological vector spaces. Assume $\tau_1$ is strictly finer than $\tau_2$.

Is there any examples of $E, \tau_1, \tau_2$, such that the dual of $(E, \tau_1)$ is the same (as set of linear functions $E\to{\mathbb C}$) as the dual of $(E, \tau_2)$?

Comment: Another example is the Mackey topology. This is the topology of uniform convergence on convex weakly comlact subsets. It is the largest topology that preserves the dual space (whereas the weak topology is the smallest one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $E$ is normed, and $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are the strong and weak topologies, then $(E, \tau_1)$ and $(E, \tau_2)$ have the same duals, by definition: $\tau_2$ is the weakest/coarsest topology that makes the linear functionals on $E$ continuous. If $E$ is infinite-dimensional, then $\tau_1$ is strictly finer than $\tau_2$.